# How to get Linux kernel modules list from user space C code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, c

I want to get the list of kernel modules by C code, and later on print their version.

From a script this is simple:

```
cat /proc/modules
lsmod
```

and later on, run for all drivers found:

```
modinfo driver_name
```

From C code, I can open `/proc/modules`, and analyze the data there, but is there a simpler way of reading this drivers list?

Comment: Your question is about programming, therefore voting to migrate to [SO] — please don't repost there.

Comment: You might find some useful API functions in the `module.c` and `module.h` files from the Linux kernel.

Comment: On Linux, reading `/proc` and/or `/sys` is, in many cases, the official way.

Answer (score 3):

> From C code, I can open /proc/modules, and analyze the data there, but is there a simpler way of reading this drivers list?

Depends on your definition of simple. The concept in Unix land of everything being a file *does* make everything simpler in one respect, because:

```
int fd = open("/proc/modules" | O_RDONLY);

while ( read(fd, &buffer, BUFFER_LIMIT) )
{
    // parse buffer
}

close(fd);
```

involves the same set of function calls as opening and reading *any file*.

The alternative mechanism would be for the kernel to allocate some memory in your process' address space pointing to that information (and you could probably do this with a custom system call) but there's really no need - as you've seen, this way works very well not just with C, but with scripts also.

Comment: It's probably even easier with fopen()/fgets(), as the /proc/modules is line based.

Comment: @nos definitely agreed. Feel free to change the code sample :)